# What is the difference between link and rich type in oEmbed?

Tags: oembed

I would like to add embed info to my site using `oEmbed` tag. I am confused between `link` type and `rich` type on which context I should use both.

Here is the [oEmbed documentation link](http://oembed.com/) which doesn't make me clear.

Any advice in this regard is much appreciated ! Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Link** type can be used when you wish to provide generic meta data about the url title, author_name etc... without providing html content or url associated with the requested url

**Rich**  type can be used when you would like to provide html content (which could be embedded within external sites) along with width and height of the iframe.